# open anchor tag with click event in a new tab

Tags: angular, anchor

I have a button and inside that I have placed the anchor tag, and i have binded a click event to the anchor tag , i want to open it in a new tab. I had tried with target="_blank" but doesnt work. It still opens in the same tab.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary"><a target="_blank" (click)="getDirection()">Directions</a></button>

getDirection() {
    this.origin = { lat: 24.799534, lng: 120.975555 };
   // this.origin = { lat: 13.0191018, lng: 77.6642952 };
    this.destination = { lat: 24.799524, lng: 120.975017 };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open a window by calling the open method on the Window object and passing in a URL.

**Componenet.html:**

```
<a target="_blank" (click)="getDirection()">Directions</a>
```

**Component.ts:**

```
  public getDirection() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
  }
```

**Stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxnrap

Comment: But in my getDirection method, i am passing origin and destination as mentioned above. There is no URL as such in my method. Can u help me how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the origin? Display it to the user or open a Google map?

Comment: It basically opens the direction  in map view  <agm-direction [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary"><a target="_blank" (click)="getDirection()">Directions</a></button>
                </agm-direction>

Comment: Okay I see, you are going to have to pass in the URL to that component to open a new tab with the map in it. You are also going to have to pass the origin and destination parameters to the new window via the query string since the component binding wont work.